# Присвоение в python

Tags: python

я новичок в `python`. Увидел такой код:
a, b = c

Что это значит? Я знаю что поменять местами это a, b = b, a. А что значит то, что я написал?

Comment: Это значит, что в `c` лежит, например, кортеж или список из двух элементов, и `a` принимает значение первого элемента (`c[0]`), а `b` - второго (`c[1]`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
a, b = b, a
```

Семантически эквивалентно следующей записи

```py
(a, b) = (b, a)
```

Т.е. слева имеем кортеж переменных, которым будем присваивать значения, справа - кортеж присваиваемых значений.

В вашем случае `c` справа должен быть списком, кортежем или другим итерируемым типом, содержащим ровно два элемента, например

```py
c = (b, a)
a, b = c
```

что очень приблизительно соответствует следующей последовательности действий

```py
c = (b, a)
a = c[0]
b = c[1]
```

Стоит добавить, что левая часть выражения настоящим кортежем не является, это просто часть синтаксиса множественного присваивания, и она может быть гораздо сложнее, например:

```
>>> [*a, (b, *c)] = (1, 2, 3, (4, 5, 6))
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
4
>>> c
[5, 6]
```

Comment: спасибо. А может быть такое, что в с будет не 2 а больше значений или обязательно сколько слева столько и справа должно быть?

Comment: Обязательно должно быть одинаковое количество, но лишние элементы можно "проигнорировать", например, вот так `a, b, *_ = c`

Comment: Круто, спасибо! и последний вопрос. А куда записываются тогда лишние элементы?

Comment: В список с именем `_`. На самом деле имя может быть любым, но называя переменную так вы даете понять тем, кто будет читать код, в том числе себе через месяц :) что этот результат в программе не используется.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь!